# "unable to read memory" when filling 2D dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays

The code below fails at the `for` loop that fills the dynamic 2D array when trying to fill the first element of the array.

The debugger tells me that it is unable to read the memory.

During this run, `rows = 7` and `cols = 20`.

```
// sets rows to number of newline characters in the file

int rows = countRows("BookMaze.txt") + 1;  /* +1 bc last row has no                     
                                              newline char */

// sets number of columns to number of characters on a single row in a file
int cols = countCols("BookMaze.txt");

char **p_rows;

// allocate
p_rows = new char*[rows];
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    p_rows[rows] = new char[cols];

// fill
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        p_rows[i][j] = '*';
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no need to use array `new` in C++ unless you are writing a container like `std::vector`, which is also the appropriate replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo/bug here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    p_rows[rows] = new char[cols];
           ^^^^
```

It should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    p_rows[i] = new char[cols];
           ^
```

Note that you should really try and get away from old skool C-style memory allocations and use proper C++ containers. In this particular case `std::vector` would have been a much better choice than raw C-style arrays.

Comment: RE: vectors, I agree 100%. This is an assignment for data structures class and it's required. Thanks!